# Al dar click en un botón que me seleccione una opción de mi select

Tags: javascript, php, select, onclick, options

quisiera que me ayudarán con lo siguiente:

Quiero tener un botón que al darle click  me eligiera una opción de mi menú desplegable y se quedará como focus en esa opción. Estoy ocupando PHP.

```
<Button>Escoger opción 3</Button>

<Select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option> //Está opción debería de salir en el select como seleccionada
</Select>
```

Comment: Revisa el atributo [selected](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-selected). No olvides que la documentación es tu mejor aliada.

Comment: Pero ese atributo hará que por defecto el Select agarre esa opción, yo lo que quiero es que el botón lo escoja por un evento como onclick

Comment: Por eso. Con ese evento haz que se establezca el atributo `selected` en el `option` en cuestión.

Answer (score 0):

```
function asignarSelected() {

// obtenemos la referencia del DOM del option que necesites, podes hacerlo con un id.
const d = document.querySelector("option");

// Le asignamos mediante el metodo setAttribute al atributo "selected"a la etiqueta
d.setAttribute('selected', 'selected')
}

// Le asignamos un escuchador de eventos al botón, que va a quedar a la espera del evento "click" y le pasamos la funcion que se va a ejecutar, en este caso asignarSelected.
button.addEventListener("click", asignarSelected)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahí aclare las instrucciones.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo usando un script sencillo como el siguiente:

```js
(function () {
  // obtén las referencias del botón y el dropdown:
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  var dropdwon = document.getElementById('dropdown');
  
  // agrega un handler al evento "click" del botón
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // actualiza el valor actual del dropdown cambiando la propiedad "value"
    // el valor que asignes aquí debe hacer match con alguno de los valores
    // que pusiste en el atributo "value" de los <option>
    dropdown.value = 3;
  });
})();
```

```html
<!-- asigna un identificador al botón: -->
<button id="button">Escoger opción 3</button>

<!-- asigna un identificador al dropdown: -->
<select id="dropdown">
  <!-- asigna un atributo "value" a cada option: -->
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```